# Why phpseclib unpack data error and stuck so long?

Tags: php, phpseclib

Why i am getting below error, what will be the solution.
open source: phpseclib Error: Bellow Error. Can i validate data before unpack or try catch unpack function. Thank.

> Warning: unpack(): Type C: not enough input, need 1, have 0 in
>   C:\php\examples\autoloader\phpseclib1\Net\SSH2.php on line 2146 PHP
>   Warning:  extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in
>   C:\php\examples\autoloader\phpseclib1\Net\SSH2.php on line 2146

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. But isn't the warning clear? `extract() expects parameter 1 to be array`.

Comment: What version are you running? I looked at 1.0.0-1.0.5 and 2.0.0-2.0.4, on line 2146, and didn't see `extract` on that line on any of those versions. See, for example, https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/1.0.0/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L2146 . Something else that'd assist in diagnosis - the log files. If you do `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 3);` and then post the results that may provide some insight into what's going on. But in lieu of any of that...  my guess is that the server is just never sending a response and eventually `fread` is timing out.